# GWT Activity and Places

Tags: gwt

where I can get example for Activity and places?(very basic example)which will give me complete knowledge about activity and places.I am totally confused between Activity and Places and MVP.

Comment: Surely your googling led you past this link: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: Please have a look at [DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html).

Comment: Thanks for replying AndersR.Bystrup and @Braj I already had a look at the the links you mentioned.I understood MVP however my problem is with Activity and places

Comment: Have a look at [DemoActivitiesAndPlaces#Working_Application](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/wiki/DemoActivitiesAndPlaces#Working_Application)

Answer (score 2):

There's the *mobilewebapp* sample in the GWT SDK (you can browser the sources online at: https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/2.6.0/samples/mobilewebapp/) but it makes things a bit more complex than they need to be (separating the activity from the presenter).

You can read more about places and activities on my blog though (4 articles): http://blog.ltgt.net